# Google Logo : On google maps changes to white when using styled map

Tags: css, angularjs, google-maps

When using styled map feature the google logo changes to white. Why is that so? any solution to retain its colors?

White Logo

```
 <ng-map center="41.53772, -100.1153" zoom="6" styles="[{featureType:'transit.line',elementType:'geometry',stylers:[{color:'#Bf5fff'},{visibility:'on'}]}]" ></ng-map>
```

Normal Logo:

```
<ng-map center="41.53772, -100.1153" zoom="6"></ng-map>
```